# Writing an expression in terms of vectorization operator $\mbox{vec} (X)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, kronecker-product, vectorization

I am new with vectorization and Kronecker products. I need to write the scalar value

$$\mathbf{a}^{T}\mathbf{X}\left(\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{a}$$

in terms of $\mathrm{vec}\left(\mathbf{X}\right)$ not $\mathbf{X}$, where:

- $\mathbf{X}$ is $N\times R$
- $\mathbf{a}$ is $N\times1$
- $N\geq R$

---

**Note:** The [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) of a matrix is a linear transformation which converts the matrix into a column vector. Specifically, the vectorization of an $m \times n$ matrix $A$, denoted by $\mbox{vec} (A)$, is the $mn \times 1$ column vector obtained by stacking the columns of the matrix $A$ on top of one another.

Comment: What is the definition of that vec operator?

Comment: the vectorization of a matrix is a linear transformation which converts the matrix into a column vector. Specifically, the vectorization of an m×n matrix A, denoted by vec(A), is the mn × 1 column vector obtained by stacking the columns of the matrix A on top of one another (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics))

Comment: If $N = R$, then the expression reduces to $a^Ta$, entirely independent of $X$.